# In apache storm topology pass userdefined object from one Bolt to another Bolt

Tags: apache-storm

I have two bolts

bolt 1
bolt 2

now the requirement is bolt1 need to pass user-defined object which contains

```
list of tweets
list of no of occurrences of tweets
```

bolt 2 takes both the tweets and publish them to redis.